# NodeJS file accessing issue

Tags: node.js, express, directory

I have a public folder ( like this

- \css
- \js
- \components

  - \images

    - \image-1.jpg
  - \icons

) in a node project i want to access the image in html like
`<img src="images/image-1.jpg">`
but in browser shows an err

however,
I've used
`app.use(express.static("public"))` like that in app.js file
but it didn't work
I've also tried
`app.use("\images", express.static(__dirname + 'public/components/images')`
but result was same

I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you are a beginner to all of this. You are making a simple mistake. You mentioned that images are inside components at path /images. So you should be able to access images like `/components/images/image-1.jpg`. You are not able to access images because `/images` is not a direct child of `public` directory.

Similarly, all CSS and JS files can be accessed `/css/filepath` and `/js/filepath` respectively.